# Local IDE submits Spark tasks to remote Yarn, remote Yarn cannot access local Driver

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

My code configuration and netstat of the local Driver port are shown below. It is possible to submit tasks to Yarn, but I found that during the task execution process, I need to remotely connect to my local Driver port, but I cannot connect. I submitted the task using Mac and found that the local Driver port is not open to external IPs, so I cannot connect back remotely. What should I do?

`spark version 3.2.1`

````
    sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", Configure.spark_serializer)
    sparkConf.set("spark.driver.host", InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostAddress)
    sparkConf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.hostname", "x.x.x.x")
    sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.jars", "hdfs:///spark-jars/*")
    sparkConf.set("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://x.x.x.x:9083")
    sparkConf.set("spark.executor.instance", "4")
    sparkConf.set("spark.executor.memory", "4096M")
    sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.queue", "test")
    sparkConf.setMaster("yarn")
    sparkConf.setAppName("MyYarnClient")```

netstat -anvp tcp | grep 49934
tcp4 0 0 192.168.31.12.49934 *.* LISTEN 131022 131022 61055
````